Twilio sync job which pulls messages from Twilio server got failed
My org started getting this error constantly after a couple days of running a custom flow process to send and receive sms messages through twilio. We were not getting any inbound messages, just this error.
We tried updating the package, adjusting the sync settings, deleting and reinstalling the package. Nothing worked.
Finally we found the problem, our messsaging service under the integration tab has an incoming message handling setting which was set to "Drop the message".
When we configured the process originally we used the option "Autocreate a conversation" but it seems that somehow got reset/switched off by itself, and it auto-reassigned to drop the message.
We followed the installation instructions to setup the webhook instead and that seemed to fix it but I am sure re-creating the conversation service and setting it to that could also work.
